# how to fetch value from an array and check its range in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have included given code and its working fine

```
def check_ip
  start = IPAddr.new(10.10.0.10).to_i
  last = IPAddr.new(20.10.10.16).to_i        
  begin
    ip_pool = IpPool.pluck(:start_ip, :end_ip)
    # [["10.10.10.12", "10.10.10.15"], ["192.168.1.13", "192.168.1.13"]]
    low = IPAddr.new("10.10.10.12").to_i
    high = IPAddr.new("10.10.10.15").to_i     
    # it will check so on with ["192.168.1.13", "192.168.1.13"] values too       
    raise ArgumentError, I18n.t('errors.start')  if ((low..high)===start or (low..high)===last      
  end
  rescue ArgumentError => msg
    self.errors.add(:start, msg)
    return false
  end
  return true
end
```

Please guide me on how to implement this code without giving static value IPAddr.new(**"10.10.10.12"**).to_i  I want to add values dynamically which I am fetching in ip_pool array so in low and high I am giving static values which are present in an array how could I give this values dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an array of `low`/`high`, you probably want to check all items in it:

```
begin
  IpPool.pluck(:start_ip, :end_ip).each do |(low,high)|
    raise ArgumentError, I18n.t('errors.start') \
      if (low..high) === start || (low..high) === last      
  end
  true
rescue ArgumentError => msg
  self.errors.add(:start, msg)
  false
end
```

Please note that I have the code a bit cleaned up:

- removed superfluous `return`s;
- corrected `begin-rescue` clause (there was a superfluous `end` right before `rescue`, that actually addressed `rescue` to the whole function body.

Comment: but in this we are iterating it is there any solution that i will not iterate it because if there are thousands of record then it will iterate about thousand times

Comment: If you want to check against the only element in `IpPool` you might use `IpPool.first` or `IpPool.detect { CONDITION }` or `IpPool.select { CONDITION }` in place of `IpPool.each`, but your question means probably that I misunderstood your requirements.